# Unity 3D iOS Game Build Fail Xcode 8.32: "clang error linker command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, xcode6, linker-errors

**Details:**

- Unity: 5.6.0f3
- Xcode: Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)
- Build: Virtual Reality iOS Mobile Game (the only thing I changed in build settings was the color profile from gamma to linear...)

I'm a beginner at Unity 3D and want to test build my game on iOS through Xcode.
However, I have tried many times and this error consistently pops up.

> Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> ld: 1446 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7

```
Ld /Users/Jolly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aqqtjpzyrdxrdefeowhehdcbavdc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/test.app/test normal armv7
cd "/Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3 alpha test"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.2
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk -L/Users/Jolly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aqqtjpzyrdxrdefeowhehdcbavdc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/Jolly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aqqtjpzyrdxrdefeowhehdcbavdc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher -L/Users/Jolly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aqqtjpzyrdxrdefeowhehdcbavdc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac -L/Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL\ STUFF/RMIT/Year\ 2/VR\ story/Builds/0.3\ alpha\ test/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries -L/Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL\ STUFF/RMIT/Year\ 2/VR\ story/Builds/0.3\ alpha\ test -L/Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL\ STUFF/RMIT/Year\ 2/VR\ story/Builds/0.3\ alpha\ test/Libraries -L/Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL\ STUFF/RMIT/Year\ 2/VR\ story/Builds/0.3\ alpha\ test/Libraries/Plugins/iOS -F/Users/Jolly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aqqtjpzyrdxrdefeowhehdcbavdc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/Jolly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aqqtjpzyrdxrdefeowhehdcbavdc/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/test.LinkFileList -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/Jolly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aqqtjpzyrdxrdefeowhehdcbavdc/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/test-LinkMap-normal-armv7.txt -miphoneos-version-min=9.2 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/Jolly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aqqtjpzyrdxrdefeowhehdcbavdc/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/test_lto.o -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGVRSDK -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lc++ -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreText -framework CoreVideo -framework GLKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -ObjC -framework MediaToolbox -liPhone-lib -framework CoreText -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -lgvrunity -weak_framework Metal -weak_framework Security -lPods-Unity-iPhone -framework GLKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Jolly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aqqtjpzyrdxrdefeowhehdcbavdc/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/test_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Jolly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-aqqtjpzyrdxrdefeowhehdcbavdc/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/test.app/test
```

There's too much to show so I will just show a snippet of the repeating code:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GVRAppearanceConfigurationUtils in:
    /Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3 alpha test/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a(GVRAppearanceConfigurationUtils_473839876bdc9859610fc4ebacde705c.o)
    /Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3 alpha test/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/libgvrunity.a(GVRAppearanceConfigurationUtils_473839876bdc9859610fc4ebacde705c.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GVRAppearanceConfigurationUtils in:
    /Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3 alpha test/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a(GVRAppearanceConfigurationUtils_473839876bdc9859610fc4ebacde705c.o)
    /Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3 alpha test/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/libgvrunity.a(GVRAppearanceConfigurationUtils_473839876bdc9859610fc4ebacde705c.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GVRAudioEngine._engine in:
    /Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3 alpha test/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a(GVRAudioEngine_91e63440cd39d6269dadebd554789f11.o)
    /Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3 alpha test/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/libgvrunity.a(GVRAudioEngine_91e63440cd39d6269dadebd554789f11.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GVRAudioEngine in:
    /Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3 alpha test/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a(GVRAudioEngine_91e63440cd39d6269dadebd554789f11.o)
    /Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3 alpha test/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/libgvrunity.a(GVRAudioEngine_91e63440cd39d6269dadebd554789f11.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GVRAudioEngine in:
    /Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3 alpha test/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a(GVRAudioEngine_91e63440cd39d6269dadebd554789f11.o)
    /Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3 alpha test/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/libgvrunity.a(GVRAudioEngine_91e63440cd39d6269dadebd554789f11.o)
etc... (1400 more lines)
```

**UPDATE:**
I deleted "arm64" in Build Setting > Architectures, and the warning stopped appearing, but error still occurs

<strike>warning: arm64 function not
4-byte aligned: ltmp0 from /Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL
STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3 alpha
test/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from
/Users/Jolly/Documents/SCHOOL STUFF/RMIT/Year 2/VR story/Builds/0.3
alpha test/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)</strike>

Here are the errors that popped up:
[screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Iwp.png)
I don't know what's going on :/ But help is greatly appreciated :D

Comment: Please try to add more details, the particular piece of code you think might be causing this, your hypothesis about how it can be solved or again what's causing this. More information you can give, the better.

Comment: Can you provide what version of Xcode (8.0, 8.1 etc) and what version of Unity you are using

Comment: @Maxin Fedotov Thanks for the reply! I'm not too sure what part of the code is causing the error, but maybe the warnings that came with it will have some clues?

Comment: @zfetters Updated!

Comment: You need to get more information about the actual link error instead of the other warnings, I think.  Go to the Report Navigator, select the link error line with the red flag, expand it by clicking the button on the far right edge of that line, paste the details into your question.

Comment: @Phillip-Mills Apparently it's a duplicate problem?
"ld: 1446 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7"

Comment: Apparently you're usinglibraries called libGVRSDK.a and libgvrunity.a.  It would seem that either one contains the other or they both contain a same third item.  Guessing here, but I'd start by removing the GVRSDK reference and see what happened.

Comment: @ Phillip-Mills Thanks for the reply! Unity built the files so I'm not sure what they are. The GVR sdk is the Google VR sdk file used to run VR on mobile. Beginner question but how can I remove the reference and what does it do?

Comment: Not sure; GVR and Unity are both alien to me.  On the other hand, I found something that sounds like someone fixing the same problem: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/234

Comment: @ Phillip-Mills Completely removing GVR allowed me to build the game without any problems.. However this is a VR project so it might be a problem haha. I will try the solution provided in your link and update you later.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to Phillip Mills for finding a link to the solution!

Quoting from the website,

> 1. Copy the GVROverlayView.h file from Pods/Headers/Public/GVRSDK folder to the top-level Classes folder.Open the main .xcodeproj file.
> 2. Delete the libPods-Unity-iPhone.a file from the left pane.
> 3. Under Build Settings, double-click the first line in Other Linker Flags. [Screenshot Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nruxc.png)
> 4. Delete the $(inherited) line.
> 5. Build the project.
> 6. Profit.

Credits to: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/234

Comment: This workaround is probably not the way to fix this issue long term.  It will not go away without properly reimporting the GoogleVRForUnity.unitypackage.

Answer (score 0):

I've also added comment to https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/234 linked above.  I'll duplicate here....

The above described issue is actually a different issue than [#259](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/259), resulting from upgrading the GoogleVR unity package, without deleting all references to the old libgvrunity.a.

If libGVRSDK.a and libgvrunity.a are creating a mass of conflicting symbols, you need to reimport the GoogleVRForUnity.unitypackage.  But first you need to go through your Assets/Plugins dir and delete any references to GVR, including libgvrunity.a. Unity's package manager does not delete files from previously imported packages that conflict with package updates.